# The compiler doesnt show errors but I get no output. Whats wrong?

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to write a small code that generates a random number between 2 and 100 and then checks if its a perfect number. I don't get any bugs from the compiler but the output doesn't show my `cout` lines like " x is a perfect number". Can someone help me with finding the reason?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

bool PerfectCheck(int x) {

    int t; // divisor

    int sum; //  sum of divisors

    for (t = 0; t <= x; t++ ) {
        if (x%t == 0) {
            sum = sum + t;
        }
    }
    if (sum == x)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    int x = rand()%(100-2+1)+2;

    if (PerfectCheck(x) == true )
        cout << x << "is a perfect number.";
    else
        cout << x << "is not a perfect number.";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Unrelated, but `if(x) return true; else return false;` can be simplyfied to `return x;` makes it more readable :)

Comment: `x%t` causes division by zero. Change `for (t = 0;` to `for (t = 1;`.

Comment: @churill I think `return sum == x` would be the "better" choice ;)

Comment: @wychmaster Yes, I used `x` as placeholder for an arbitrary condition. But, I see, that's somewhat ambigious when there is variable with this name.

Comment: Also `sum` is used unitialized. Another cause of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems in your `PerfectCheck` function. First, you don't initialize the `sum` variable, so it can start off with any value whatsoever; you should set it to zero *explicitly* in the declaration.

Second, your `for` loop starts with `t` as zero, and you check `x % t`. The modulo operator *implicitly* involves a division, so using a left-hand value of zero has the same issue as trying to divide by zero, which will cause a crash.

Third, when checking for a perfect number, don't use that number itself in the sum; so, stop your loop with `t < x` instead of `t <= x`.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you can simplify the return statement. The code below works, in the tests I have performed:

```cpp
bool PerfectCheck(int x)
{
    int sum = 0; //  sum of divisors - MUST BE INITIALIZED (to zero)
    for (int t = 1; t < x; t++) { // DO NOT INCLUDE X ITSELF!!
        if (x % t == 0) {
            sum += t;
        }
    }
    return (sum == x); // This will already give a "true" or "false" bool value.
}
```

*You could actually make the code a tiny bit more 'efficient', by initializing `sum` to `1` and then starting the loop from `t = 2` (all numbers divide by 1, after all).*

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Even after doing that, no numbers in 100 iterations (used for loop to execute the code 100 times) shows 'perfect number'. I was coding what exactly you've coded. But the program just shows *Not a perfect number*.

Comment: My mistake - sorry! See edit: Don't include the number itself in the test/summation.

Comment: Thank you so much. the division by 0 was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`if (x%t == 0)` calculates the remainder after dividing `x` by `t` and compares the result with 0. That statement is correct, but look at the previous code `for (t = 0; t <= x; t++ ) {`. The first value of `t` is 0, so you have a division by zero. More than likely that is crashing your program which is why you see no output. Change `for (t = 0; t <= x; t++ ) {` to `for (t = 1; t <= x; t++ ) {`.

Also I believe the definition of a perfect number does not include division by the number itself. So the for loop should actually be `for (t = 1; t < x; t++ ) {`.

Finally you are using the `sum` variable to add up the divisors but you do not give it an initial value. Your code should say `int sum = 0;`.

Three errors in a ten line program (plus various style issues). Imagine how many errors here might be in a 5000 line program. Programming is tricky, you have to be very focused and get your code exactly right, nearly right is not good enough.